# Tratar imagen en PHP desde php://input

Tags: php

¡Saludos!

Obtengo la imagen desde `php://input` a través de un `byte array` del cliente, donde trato de conseguir información cómo tipo, dimensiones, etc.

Para ello uso el código:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$image = imagecreatefromstring($input);
```

Y con `exif_imagetype($image)` obtendría el tipo, etc. También trato de crear otras imágenes a partir de ella:

```
$new = imagescale($image, 50, 50);
```

Al parecer `imagecreatefromstring`no me esta funcionando.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no está funcionando? ¿Se muestra algún error en el log?

Comment: Lanza que no ha podido crear la imagen del string

Comment: Prueba a ver si consigues imprimir qué error te da con alguna función del estilo de `error_get_last` o similar

Comment: Si es un byte array deberías descodificar $data = base64_decode($byte_array); $image = imagecreatefromstring($data);